I don't want the boxes to be read as special character or letters
This is the image:

This is the sample image that i will convert into text.
And here is the output:
***"|
| .**
indicators (Bids:
S.1.4.1. valid Certificate of Registration and **LJ Poy |**
Professional Licensure Examination for
Teachers (LET);
S.1.4.2. Master’s degree in education or in any of :
**__** the allied fields; and **—**
S.1.4.3. comply with other requirements of the CHED. **_—!**
S.2. Other qualifications such as the following are considered: **|__|**
"*

Those bold letters/characters are unwanted. I think it's because of the boxes.
Can anyone help me fix this?
Here's my code:
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
from progress.bar import Bar
import pytesseract  # type: ignore
import uuid
import fnmatch
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

directory = "D:/Python/Projects/Pdf_OCR/pdf_file"

files = Path(directory).glob("*.png")

rand_filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
create_text_file = open(f"{rand_filename}.txt", "x")

total_imgs = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(directory), "*png")
bar = Bar("Processing", max=len(total_imgs))

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

open_text_file = open(f"{rand_filename}.txt", "w")


for file in files:
    img = Image.open(file)

    custom_config = r"-l eng --psm 6 --oem 3"
    open_text_file.write(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=custom_config))
    bar.next()

open_text_file.close
bar.finish()


As for removing the non-alpha characters, one option would be to limit the characters tesseract is 'allowed' to read, using a whitelist.  Specifically, add something such as -c tessedit_char_whitelist=abc to your custom_config. Note that f-strings and built-in the string library can be used to construct the list of acceptable characters (easily).

Croppe you image and focus on the interested content only.
